# Blazor wasm invoke javascript, pass large array is very slow

Tags: javascript, performance, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm app. In that I am invoking a javascript function that receives an array of double.
This is very slow, especially when the array is large.

For a  test see the code below:

javascript ("test.js"):

```
function testSumArray(array) {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    sumArray(array);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log('From JS, time to sum: ' + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + ' s');
}

function sumArray(array) {
    var i;
    var s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        s += array[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

And c# code (index.razor):

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

@using System.Text
@using BlazorWasmOnlyTest.Shared
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@TestInvokeJS">Test invoke js</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private int _id;
    private string _status = "";
    private DataInputFileForm _dataInputFileForm;

    private async void TestInvokeJS()
    {
        var n = 100000;
        var array = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        var w = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        w.Start();
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("testSumArray",array);
        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"C# time to invoke js and sum: {w.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000:F3} s");
    }
}
```

And for completion - index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorWasmOnlyTest</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Running this once gives the following output on my machine:

> From JS, time to sum: 0.0037800000282004476 s

> C# time to invoke js and sum: 7.000 s

That seems like a pretty high overhead time... Does anyone know if there is a way to speed this up (the real function does something I presently cannot do in Blazor/C# - updating a layer in [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/))

EDIT:
I have tried the synchronous method described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1), without any difference in execution time.

c#:

```
    var jsInProcess2 = (IJSInProcessRuntime)JSRuntime;
    jsInProcess2.InvokeVoid("testSumArray", array);
```

js: javascript same as `testSumArray` above.

EDIT 2:

I have tried passing a JSON string with synchronous interop:

c#:

```
    var jsInProcess3 = (IJSInProcessRuntime)JSRuntime;
    var array_json3 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(array);
    jsInProcess3.InvokeVoid("testSumArray3", array_json);
```

js:

```
function testSumArray3(array_json_string) {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    var array = JSON.parse(array_json_string);
    var s = sumArray(array);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log('From JS, time to sum: ' + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + ' s');
    console.log('Array sum = ' + s);
}
```

and with JSON string and InvokeUnmarshalled js interopcall:

c#:

```
    var jsInProcess4 = (Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSRuntime)JSRuntime;
    var array_json4 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(array);
    jsInProcess4.InvokeUnmarshalled<string,string>("testSumArray4", array_json4);
```

js:

```
function testSumArray4(array_mono_json_string) {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    const array_json_string = BINDING.conv_string(array_mono_json_string);
    var array = JSON.parse(array_json_string);
    var s = sumArray(array);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log('From JS, time to sum: ' + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + ' s');
    console.log('Array sum = ' + s);
}
```

All methods take approximately the same time, 6-7 secs to complete (of that about 0.0015-0.006 seconds in the javascript function).

I have tried to figure out how to call unmarshalled passing an array, using `BINDING.mono_array_to_js_array` found in in this [file](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/sdks/wasm/src/binding_support.js) but that throws a long error.
c#:

```
    var sum = jsInProcess4.InvokeUnmarshalled<double[],double>("testSumArray5",array)
```

js:

```
function testSumArray5(array_in) {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    var array = BINDING.mono_array_to_js_array(array_in);
    console.log(array[0]);
    var s = sumArray(array);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log('From JS, time to sum: ' + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + ' s');
    console.log('Array sum = ' + s);
    return s;
}
```

### EDIT 2024-01-02

It seems that (at least with NET 8) this is no issue anymore as the default `IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync` seems to be (almost) as fast, and the `InvokeUnmarshalled` is marked `[System.Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use JSImportAttribute instead.")]` at least since NET 7. However I do not not understand the `JSImportAttribute` and I got almost as fast without any attributes.

Comment: What browser are you using? If it's going to be slow or fast with webassembly, depends on the browser's webassembly implementation. So are better than others...

Comment: @Vencovsky just quickltmy tested with chrome..

Comment: Not sure what "quickltmy" means

Comment: quickly was what I meant :) - autospeller..

Comment: And in chrome, it's still the same?

Comment: Chrome 7 seconds, Fireforx 6 seconds, Edge (v. 44) crashes..

Comment: Actually I got Edge v. 44 to run it, it took 400 seconds! (JS time = 0.018 s)

Comment: Try with .NET 5 and see if there is any improvement. Looks like the JS Interop is slowing things down when passing the array. Performance gets better when you reduce the number of array elements? How large is the array?

Comment: @user3656651 - in the test code above the size is set to 100000. When I tried looping through 10-100000 (increasing by factor 10 between loops) the overhead time seemed to be increasing almost linearly with size.

Comment: Change `async void` to `async Task`, just to follow best practices. It might affect the timing a little too.

Comment: Try passing the array as an json. I think it will be faster if you pass a string than a array.

Comment: Json speed is already [a concern](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40386). The team worked hard on it, in .net5 RC1 it should be ~3x faster. But still well below JS perf. There are limits imposed by the current Wasm architecture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found the way to use .net byte or float arrays in js.

#### c#:

```
[Inject] //Injected JSRuntime from Blazor DI
private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

byte[] bytes1;
float[] floats2;
...
if (JSRuntime is IJSUnmarshalledRuntime webAssemblyJSRuntime)
{
    webAssemblyJSRuntime.InvokeUnmarshalled<byte[], float[], object> 
        ("downloadArray", bytes1, floats2);
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function downloadArray(bytes1, floats2) {
    // Easy way to convert Uint8 arrays
    var byteArray = Blazor.platform.toUint8Array(bytes1);

    // Adapted method above for float32
    var m = floats2 + 12;
    var r = Module.HEAP32[m >> 2]
    var j = new Float32Array(Module.HEAPF32.buffer, m + 4, r);
}
```

Here result is Uint8Array and Float32Array objects from byte[] and float[] respectively within a reasonable period of time.

May be there are any approaches to get js arrays because you have access to the whole .net heap from ArrayBuffers like Module.HEAPU8 (heap inside Uint8Array) or Module.HEAPF32 (heap inside Float32Array) and can easily access objects by pointer from InvokeUnmarshalled parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really speeds things up!

Comment: Thank you this works like a charm, and the performance increase is noticeable.

Comment: Hi @lg101, thank you very much for your research! I am investigating the option to read char[] from HEAP. Could you please tell me how do we get "r"? and why do we add 4 to "m"?