# What is the most efficient way to pass an array to JavaScript from C# in a Blazor application

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have a Blazor application. I want to regularly pass an array of doubles from the C# side to the JavaScript side.

So, on the JavaScript side I have a function like so:

```
function Update(doubleArray)
{
    // Do some processing here
}
```

and on the C# side I have:

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Update",
                                doubleArray);
```

where doubleArray is of type double[]

Now, to test the speed of things I just regularly update the first four values in doubleArray and send the array over to the JavaScript side and draw a line on a canvas by treating the first four values as coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2.

If the size of the array is a few hundred then things run nice and smoothly, but if the array gets to be around 1000 elements then things start to slow down rather drastically.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the passing of the array from C# to JavaScript?

Comment: Are you really experiencing a meaningful slowdown from 1000 double values? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: @gnitsuk - how are you measuring the time taken? Are you sure there isn't a problem in the JS function that you're calling rather than the transport between Blazor and JS?

Comment: I tested as follows: I altered things so that the JS code does not use the array that it is passed. I just draw a circle at a location which I update on the JS side each time. With the array having 1000 items the animation is slow. If, in the C#, immediately before the call to JS function I set the array to say 10 items, animation is fast again. So it would seem like the passing of the array is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approch best fits your use case :

In you Blazor component :

```
    @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

    @code {
    string[] myArray = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var dotNetObjectRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("yourJavaScriptFunction", dotNetObjectRef, myArray);
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void HandleArray(string[] myArray)
    {
        // Use myArray in your C# code
    }
}
```

In your javascript file :

```
   window.yourJavaScriptFunction = function(dotNetObjectRef, myArray) {        
    dotNetObjectRef.invokeMethodAsync('HandleArray', myArray); // Call the .NET method using the dotNetObjectRef
   };
```

However, you can check and see if the time difference between below alternative approach for time difference.

#### Alternative Approach :

In Blazor component:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code {
    string[] myArray = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("yourJavaScriptFunction", myArray);
    }
}
```

In your javascript file :

```
window.yourJavaScriptFunction = function(myArray) {
    
    console.log(myArray); // Use myArray in your JavaScript code
};
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I was not aware of DotNetObjectReference. From google I read "indicating that the value should not be serialized as JSON but instead should be passed as a reference". That sounds promising. Certainly I can understand that if my array is being converted to JSON each time then this would be costly. I shall try it.

Comment: mmm, looking further I see that the DotNetObjectReference answer would not appear to help me. I am still having to pass the array over, just that I also pass the DotNetObjectReference as well. I tried it anyway but it makes no difference, I may be misunderstanding how to use DotNetObjectReference. I will need to read further. If it is the case that my array is being converted to JSON then if there is a way to avoid this that's what I would need.

Comment: ok. Thanks. definitely passing large arrays is the issue. I realized my error in my last comment. I now no longer pass the array but call a method on the DotNetObjectReference  to get the array. Same issue. I am going to refactor and maintain my array on the JS side to avoid the need to pass it over. I'll also look at something I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902497/blazor-wasm-invoke-javascript-pass-large-array-is-very-slow Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just wanted to add that my last comment was not fully correct. I've done more testing and the approach of using DotNetObjectReference suggested by Selaka Nanayakkara does provide a noticeable increase in speed. I had missed it because I was testing with so very many points that both methods were really slow. Thanks again to Selaka Nanayakkara.